# Como criar objetos sequenciais?

Tags: php

Antes de tudo, quero mencionar que sou extremamente iniciante em POO.

Bom, estive quebrando a cabeça nos últimos dias, mas não consegui chegar a uma conclusão sozinho, tampouco consegui obter respostas relativas à minha dúvida (talvez porque a dúvida seja tão grande que eu não saiba como pesquisar corretamente).

Gostaria de saber como eu poderia criar um método de uma classe 'Database' que fizesse a inserção no banco de dados com a seguinte sintaxe:

```
$user = Database::table('users')->where('name', 'John')->first();
```

Onde:

`table()` é o método que determina em qual entidade será feita o `SELECT`;

`where()` seria o correspondente ao `WHERE` do SQL e `first()` determina que somente o primeiro resultado da query deve ser retornado.

A dúvida não é sobre SQL, mas sim sobre como criar a sintaxe de cima.

Comment: Está usando Framework Laravel ?

Comment: isso é apenas um exemplo? porque se existirem mais de um usuário com esse nome, ele ira sempre pegar o primeiro registro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem inúmeras maneiras de se implementar isso, mas na essência basta entender exatamente o que a linha de código faz:

```
$user = Database::table('users')->where('name', 'John')->first();
```

`Database` é uma classe que possui um método estático `table` responsável por instanciar um objeto para a tabela `'users'` e retorná-lo. O método `where` é o que chamamos de método modificador, pois ele recebe parâmetros que modificarão o próprio objeto e retorná-lo no novo estado. O método `first` será responsável por executar a SQL gerada com as instruções anteriores e retornar o resultado.

Bem simplificadamente seria algo como:

```
class Database
{
    private $table;
    private $conditions = [];
    private $columns = ['*'];

    private function __construct($table)
    {
        $this->table = $table;
    }

    public static function table($table): self
    {
        return new self($table);
    }

    public function where($column, $value): self
    {
        $this->conditions[] = "{$column} = '{$value}'";

        return $this;
    }

    public function select(array $columns): self
    {
        $this->columns = $columns;

        return $this;
    }

    public function first()
    {
        $columns = join(', ', $this->columns);
        $sql = "SELECT {$columns} FROM {$this->table}";

        if (count($this->conditions) > 0) {
            $sql .= " WHERE ";
            $sql .= join(" AND ", $this->conditions);
        }

        $sql .= " LIMIT 1";

        return $sql;
    }
}
```

Para simplificar, fiz o método `first` retornar a SQL gerada ao invés de executá-la e retornar o resultado, pois isso dependeria diretamente de ter o banco de dados e dificulta a reprodução da resposta.

Desta forma, podemos fazer:

```
$users = Database::table('users')->first();
// string(27) "SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1"

$users = Database::table('users')->select(['id', 'nome'])->first();
// string(34) "SELECT id, nome FROM users LIMIT 1"

$users = Database::table('users')->where('nome', 'João')->first();
// string(48) "SELECT * FROM users WHERE nome = 'João' LIMIT 1"

$users = Database::table('users')->select(['id', 'nome'])->where('nome', 'João')->first();
// string(55) "SELECT id, nome FROM users WHERE nome = 'João' LIMIT 1"
```

Entre outras...